# Deserialize to IEnumerable class using Newtonsoft Json.Net

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin.ios, json.net, ienumerable

I have a project that is currently using Json.Net for Json deserialization classes like these:

```
public class Foo {
    public Guid FooGuid { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Bar> Bars { get; set; }
}

public class Bar {
    public Guid BarGuid { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

So far it works fine.

To make iteration simpler at one point I made `Foo` class implement `IEnumerable<Bar>` like this:

```
public class Foo : IEnumerable<Bar> {
    public Guid FooGuid { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Bar> Bars { get; set; }

    public IEnumerator<Bar> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return Bars.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}

public class Bar {
    public Guid BarGuid { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

But then it fails deserializing the object. The error is confusing, as it said that it cannot deserialize `FooGuid` field, but removing the `IEnumerable` interface works again.

The problem is the same in both MonoTouch and MonoDroid environments in simulator or device.

Any clue about how to make it work?

---

Added code to reproduce this issue:

```
public static class Tests {
    public static void SerializeAndDeserializeFoo() {
        // Serialize and deserialize Foo class
        var element = new Foo
        {
            FooGuid = Guid.NewGuid(),
            Name = "Foo name",
            Bars = new List<Bar> {
                new Bar { BarGuid = Guid.NewGuid(), Description = "Bar description" },
                new Bar { BarGuid = Guid.NewGuid(), Description = "Bar description" },
                new Bar { BarGuid = Guid.NewGuid(), Description = "Bar description" }
            }
        };

        var serializedObject = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(element);
        Console.WriteLine("Serialized Foo element: {0}", serializedObject);

        // Exception if Foo implements IEnumerable
        var deserializedObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Foo>(serializedObject);
        Console.WriteLine("Foo deserialization worked!");
    }

    public static void SerializeAndDeserializeEnumerableFoo() {
        // Serialize and deserialize Foo class
        var element = new EnumerableFoo
        {
            FooGuid = Guid.NewGuid(),
            Name = "Foo name",
            Bars = new List<Bar> {
                new Bar { BarGuid = Guid.NewGuid(), Description = "Bar description" },
                new Bar { BarGuid = Guid.NewGuid(), Description = "Bar description" },
                new Bar { BarGuid = Guid.NewGuid(), Description = "Bar description" }
            }
        };

        var serializedObject = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(element);
        Console.WriteLine("Serialized EnumerableFoo element: {0}", serializedObject);

        try {
            // Exception if Foo implements IEnumerable
            var deserializedObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<EnumerableFoo>(serializedObject);
            Console.WriteLine("EnumerableFoo deserialization worked!");
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            Console.WriteLine("EnumerableFoo deserialization failed!");
            throw;
        }
    }
}

public class EnumerableFoo : IEnumerable<Bar> {
    public Guid FooGuid { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Bar> Bars { get; set; }

    public IEnumerator<Bar> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return Bars.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}

public class Foo {
    public Guid FooGuid { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Bar> Bars { get; set; }
}

public class Bar {
    public Guid BarGuid { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Sample project: https://www.dropbox.com/s/27i58aiz71dylkw/IEnumerableJson.zip

Comment: How about posting a self-contained compilable code? Since i can't reproduce it.

Comment: @L.B Added sample code and sample project.

Comment: You don't need to implement `IEnumerable<Bar>`. Just put this method `public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
            {
                return Bars.GetEnumerator();
            }` to  `EnumerableFoo` (removing other GetEnumerators) , it will work in **foreach**

Comment: the JSON.net docs (http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/SerializationGuide.htm) discuss the limitations of serializing IEnumerables.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

From the [Json.Net documentation](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/?topic=html/SerializationGuide.htm):

> **IEnumerable, Lists and Arrays**
>
> .NET lists (types that inherit from IEnumerable) and .NET arrays are converted to JSON arrays. Because JSON arrays only support a range of values and not properties, any additional properties and fields declared on .NET collections are not serialized. In situations where a JSON array is not wanted the JsonObjectAttribute can be placed on a .NET type that implements IEnumerable to force the type to be serialized as a JSON object instead.

In other words, since your class implements `IEnumerable<T>`,  Json.Net thinks it is a list.  To get around this, simply decorate your class with the `[JsonObject]` attribute.  This will force Json.Net to serialize and deserialize it as a normal class, which is what you want in this case.

```
[JsonObject]
public class EnumerableFoo : IEnumerable<Bar>
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If there is a `private` property to be serialized/deserialized `[JsonProperty]` should be used.

Example:

```
[JsonProperty]
private Sth[] sthArray;
```