# String instead of data

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, http-post

I'm trying to get data from the controller
something like this:

```
public IEnumerable<Custom> Search(string searchText = "")
    {
        return new[] { new Custom { Name = "a", Id = 1 }, new Custom { Name = "b", Id = 1 }, new Custom { Name = "c", Id = 3 } };
    }
```

But angular gives me this

> m
>   u
>   s
>   i
>   c
>   p
>   o
>   r
>   t
>   a
>   l
>   .
>   C
>   o
>   n
>   t
>   r
>   o
>   l
>   l
>   e
>   r
>   s
>   .
>   C
>   u
>   s
>   t
>   o
>   m
>   [
>   ]

I tried add http.headers but nothing.
My code:

```
var musicportal = angular.module('musicportal', []);

musicportal.controller('SearchController', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
$scope.answer = "awesome";

$scope.search = function (text) {
    $scope.answer = text;
    $scope.pms = [];                  
    $http.post('/Home/Search', { searchText: text }).
        success(function (data, status, headers, config) {              
            $scope.pms = data;
        });
    $scope.searchText = "";
}
}]);
```

Comment: See if this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19080326/deserialize-to-ienumerable-class-using-newtonsoft-json-net) can help you.

Comment: Are you getting JSON out of this controller call?

Comment: I try use $scope.pms in angular.foreach in view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should return data as `json` e.g.

```
public ActionResult Search(string searchText = "")
{
    return Json(new { Foo = "Hello" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}

$http.post('/Home/Search', { searchText: text }).
        success(function (data, status, headers, config) {              
            $scope.pms = data.Foo;
        });
```

Now, in your case, you have a list, so you need to convert that into JSON. You can do that in ASP.NET MVC using [`JsonSerializer`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) e.g.

```
public ActionResult Search(string searchText = "")
{
    string json = "";
    var items = new[] { new Custom { Name = "a", Id = 1 }, new Custom { Name = "b", Id = 1 }, new Custom { Name = "c", Id = 3 } };

    using (var writer = new StringWriter())    
    using (var jsonWriter = new JsonTextWriter(writer))
    {
        serializer.Serialize(jsonWriter, items);
        json = writer.ToString();
    }

    return Json(json, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}

$http.post('/Home/Search', { searchText: text }).
            success(function (data, status, headers, config) {              
                $scope.pms = JSON.Parse(data);
            });
```

You may need to play about with this code, it's not perfect first time, but hopefully it will give you a head start.

Comment: Glad my answer has helped you :)