# Applying JsonDictionary attribute to dictionary

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, json.net

If I try to add the JsonDictionary attribute to a .net Dictionary(Of Integer, MyClass), the compiler tells me, that the attribute could not be applied. Why is this?

```
<JsonDictionary()>
Public ReadOnly Property monatswerte As Dictionary(Of Integer, MyClass)
```

I basically couldn't find any examples of how to use the JsonDictionary online.

Comment: I've never used it, so can't really help, but the [source code](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/JsonDictionaryAttribute.cs) has `[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Interface, AllowMultiple = false)]`, so you can only use it on a class or interface.  If (like me) you don't know how to use it, perhaps it's not the answer you are looking for - perhaps you should ask about the problem you are trying to solve instead? :-)

Comment: I added the [tag:.net] and [tag:c#] tags since the question and answer are not language specific.

Answer (score 5):

[`<JsonDictionary()>`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonDictionaryAttribute.htm) can be applied to a type (a class or interface) to force Json.NET's [default contract resolver](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_DefaultContractResolver.htm) (and its subclasses) to generate a [dictionary contract](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_JsonDictionaryContract.htm) for the type.  It is part of a family of three similar attributes:

- [`<JsonObject()>`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonObjectAttribute.htm).  Force a type to be serialized as a JSON object.  Useful to force serialization of collection properties instead of items as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19087883/3744182).
- [`<JsonArray()>`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonArrayAttribute.htm).  Force a type to serialized as a JSON array.  Possibly useful to, e.g., force a dictionary to be serialized as a key/value pair array.
- [`<JsonDictionary()>`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonDictionaryAttribute.htm).  Force a type to be interpreted as a dictionary and serialized as a JSON object.  (It must still implement `IDictionary` or `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>` for this to work, of course.)

On the face of it `<JsonDictionary()>` does not seem that useful because [`DefaultContractResolver.CreateContract(Type objectType)`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Serialization/DefaultContractResolver.cs#L1122) checks that the incoming type implements `IDictionary` before checking for any other interface implementations.  However, the attribute has several [properties](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Properties_T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonDictionaryAttribute.htm) that could be useful in customizing how a dictionary is serialized, including:

- [`NamingStrategyType`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonContainerAttribute_NamingStrategyType.htm) and [`NamingStrategyParameters`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonContainerAttribute_NamingStrategyParameters.htm) allow control of casing and name-mapping of dictionary **keys**.

  For instance, the following dictionary will always serialize its keys literally, without renaming, even if [`CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver.htm) is in use:

  ```
  <JsonDictionary(NamingStrategyType := GetType(LiteralKeyDictionaryNamingStrategy))> _
  Public Class LiteralKeyDictionary(Of TValue)
      Inherits Dictionary(Of String, TValue)
  End Class

  Public Class LiteralKeyDictionaryNamingStrategy
      Inherits DefaultNamingStrategy

      Public Sub New()
          ProcessDictionaryKeys = False
      End Sub
  End Class
  ```
- [`ItemConverterType`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonContainerAttribute_ItemConverterType.htm), [`ItemConverterParameters`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonContainerAttribute_ItemConverterParameters.htm), [`ItemIsReference`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonContainerAttribute_ItemIsReference.htm), [`ItemReferenceLoopHandling`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonContainerAttribute_ItemReferenceLoopHandling.htm)and [`ItemTypeNameHandling`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonContainerAttribute_ItemTypeNameHandling.htm) allow customization of how dictionary **values** are serialized.

  For instance, in the following dictionary type, the values are always stored with [reference preservation](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/PreserveReferencesHandlingObject.htm) enabled:

  ```
  <JsonDictionary(ItemIsReference := true)> _
  Public Class ReferenceObjectDictionary(of TKey, TValue As {Class, New})
      Inherits Dictionary(Of TKey, TValue)
  End Class
  ```

  Or, for a dictionary type containing `enum` values, you might apply [`StringEnumConverter`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/t_newtonsoft_json_converters_stringenumconverter.htm) as an `ItemConverterType` to force the values to be serialized as strings.

Answer (score 0):

@dbc's answer is great, +1'd (and this approach is a lot less messing than going the `TypeConverter` route as it's explicit). Here's an F# riff/rip-off/port:

```
[<JsonDictionary(NamingStrategyType =
                    typedefof<VerbatimKeyDictionaryNamingStrategy>)>]
type VerbatimKeyDictionary<'value>(values : IDictionary<string,'value>) =
    inherit Dictionary<string,'value>(values)
    override this.Equals other =
        let that = other :?> IDictionary<string,'value>
        that <> null
        && this.Count = that.Count
        && Seq.isEmpty (this |> Seq.except that)
    override __.GetHashCode () = 0
and VerbatimKeyDictionaryNamingStrategy() =
    inherit Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultNamingStrategy(
         ProcessDictionaryKeys = false)
```