# PascalCase for dictionary keys for specific properties in JSON.NET

Tags: c#, json, json.net

Is there a way to control how dictionary keys are serialized on a **per-property** basis?

I have written a `CamelCaseExceptDictionaryKeysResolver` which makes sure all dictionary keys are serialized PascalCase for all properties in the JObject.

Any way to do this with an attribute on the specific property?

Comment: You could subclass your dictionary and apply `[JsonDictionary(NamingStrategyType = typeof(DefaultNamingStrategy)]` as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43125855/3744182).  Does that help?

Comment: That did exactly what I wanted. Thanks!

Comment: Mark as a duplicate then, or do you need a c# implementation?