# How to make Json Serialize ignore dictionary keys

Tags: c#, json, dictionary, serialization, json.net

I'm trying to serialize a dictionary within a class and the keys inside the `CustomAttributes` dictionary are getting formatted even though I've provided the `ProcessDictionaryKeys` parameter as false.

I've added `[JsonProperty]` as shown below:

```
[JsonProperty(NamingStrategyType = typeof(SnakeCaseNamingStrategy), NamingStrategyParameters = new object[] { false, false })]
public IDictionary<string, string> CustomAttributes { get; set; }
```

my CustomAttributes data looks like this:

```
CustomAttributes = new Dictionary<string, string>()
{
    {"Custom Attribute 1", "1"},
    {"CustomAttribute 2", "2"}
}
```

and the JSON which is produced looks like:

```
custom_attributes\":{\"custom Attribute 1\":\"1\",\"customAttribute 2\":\"2\"
```

As you can see, the first letter of each of the dictionary keys are being uncapitalised. How can I stop this from happening?

EDIT: Changing the `ProcessDictionaryKeys` parameter to true doesn't seem to make any difference.

Comment: remove this `NamingStrategyType = typeof(SnakeCaseNamingStrategy)` ?

Comment: All this does is change the name of the dictionary to the default camelCase:

`customAttributes\":{\"custom Attribute 1\":\"1\",\"customAttribute 2\":\"2`

Comment: Yes, but that's your question, isn't it ? *"As you can see, the first letter of each of the dictionary keys are being uncapitalised. How can I stop this from happening?"*

Comment: No, my question is related to the keys in the dictionary, not the dictionary name. I need them to not be formatted  i.e. remain as "Custom Attribute 1", not formatted to "custom Attribute 1"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem doesn't reproduce with just the code in your question as shown in demo fiddle #1 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/WwJEJN).

Instead, you must be serializing with some global serializer settings for which  [`JsonSerializerSettings.ContractResolver.NamingStrategy.ProcessDictionaryKeys = true`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_NamingStrategy_ProcessDictionaryKeys.htm) such as [`CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver.htm):

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver(),
};
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(root, Formatting.Indented, settings);
```

Demo fiddle #2 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/3HUcvY).

Assuming that's correct, the reason that `[JsonProperty(NamingStrategyType = typeof(SnakeCaseNamingStrategy), NamingStrategyParameters = new object[] { false, false })]` does not cause the dictionary keys to be serialized verbatim is that [`JsonPropertyAttribute.NamingStrategyType`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonPropertyAttribute_NamingStrategyType.htm) only applies to the **property name itself** (here `CustomAttributes`) not the property names of property's **items**.  If you wanted to apply a naming strategy to the property's items you would need something like `ItemNamingStrategyType` -- but [`JsonPropertyAttribute`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonPropertyAttribute.htm) has no such functionality.

So, what are your options?

1. You could modify your global naming strategy to serialize dictionary names verbatim as shown in *[Keep casing when serializing dictionaries](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24143149/3744182)*.
2. You could subclass `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` and apply [`[JsonDictionary(NamingStrategyType = typeof(DefaultNamingStrategy))]`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonContainerAttribute_NamingStrategyType.htm) to it as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43125855/3744182) to *[Applying JsonDictionary attribute to dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43122509/3744182)*:

   ```
   [JsonDictionary(NamingStrategyType = typeof(DefaultNamingStrategy))]
   public class VerbatimDictionary<TKey, TValue> : Dictionary<TKey, TValue>
   {
   }
   ```

   And then later:

   ```
   CustomAttributes = new VerbatimDictionary<string, string>()
   {
       {"Custom Attribute 1", "1"},
       {"CustomAttribute 2", "2"}
   }
   ```

   Demo fiddle #3 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/xpaI6R).
3. You could introduce a [custom `JsonConverter`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm) that serializes an `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>` with the default naming strategy.  First, define the following converter:

   ```
   public class VerbatimDictionaryConverter<TKey, TValue> : JsonConverter<IDictionary<TKey, TValue>>
   {
       [JsonDictionary(NamingStrategyType = typeof(DefaultNamingStrategy))]
       class VerbatimDictionarySerializationSurrogate : IReadOnlyDictionary<TKey, TValue>
       {
           readonly IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary;

           public VerbatimDictionarySerializationSurrogate(IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary) 
           { 
               if (dictionary == null) 
                   throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(dictionary));
               this.dictionary = dictionary; 
           }
           public bool ContainsKey(TKey key) { return dictionary.ContainsKey(key); }
           public bool TryGetValue(TKey key, out TValue value) { return dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out value); }
           public TValue this[TKey key] { get { return dictionary[key]; } }
           public IEnumerable<TKey> Keys { get { return dictionary.Keys; } }
           public IEnumerable<TValue> Values { get { return dictionary.Values; } }
           public int Count { get { return dictionary.Count; } }
           public IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> GetEnumerator() { return dictionary.GetEnumerator(); }
           IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() { return GetEnumerator(); }
       }

       public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, IDictionary<TKey, TValue> value, JsonSerializer serializer)
       {
           serializer.Serialize(writer, new VerbatimDictionarySerializationSurrogate(value));
       }

       public override bool CanRead { get { return false; } }

       public override IDictionary<TKey, TValue> ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, IDictionary<TKey, TValue> existingValue, bool hasExistingValue, JsonSerializer serializer) { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
   }
   ```

   And apply it as follows:

   ```
   [JsonConverter(typeof(VerbatimDictionaryConverter<string, string>))]
   public IDictionary<string, string> CustomAttributes { get; set; }
   ```

   Demo fiddle #4 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/44r2fl).