# JSON.NET DefaultNamingStrategy not working for IDictionary

Tags: json.net

We use

```
jsonFormatterSerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
```

globally in our webapi project but for one particular Dictionary property I want to override this. This is because the strings which represent the keys in the Dictionary are having their cases transformed and I want to return the original unmodified values.
I tried this setting but it didn't work the keys were still camel case.

```
[JsonProperty(NamingStrategyType = typeof(DefaultNamingStrategy)]      
public IDictionary<string, long?> Data { get; set; }
```

Comment: Looks pretty much like a duplicate of [How to make Json Serialize ignore dictionary keys](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58501943/3744182).  There the OP is trying to add `SnakeCaseNamingStrategy` to a dictionary property rather than `DefaultNamingStrategy` and is using global serializer settings rather than explicit settings - but the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58509729/3744182) is still the same.

Comment: Does that answer your question or do you need additional help?  Applying `[JsonConverter(typeof(VerbatimDictionaryConverter<string, long?>))]` from [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58509729/3744182) to `Data` should work for you.

Comment: Excellent, thanks that really helps.